# checkbox to filter data php jQuery AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a checkbox called Active and it is always been checked when staff enter to the system and it will display the data of active worker. Now, if I uncheck the checkbox it should display the data of inactive worker and in my case it is not working. Please check my code and it will helpful for me if you provide me some solution

This is my code for checkbox

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
    <label for="activeWorker">
        <input type="checkbox" id="activeWorker" name="activeWorker" value="active" checked> Active Workers
    </label>
</div>
```

This is my code for function to reload data based on selected date range

```
function reload() {
    var dateFrom = $("#dateFrom").val();
    var dateTo = $("#dateTo").val();
    var coid = $("#selectCompanyId").val();
    var activeStatus = $("#activeWorker").val();

    var dataURL;

    alert("You have clicked the reload button. Reloading the data for the date range:" + dateFrom + " to " + dateTo + " For Company : " + coid);

    if (activeTab == "#tab-1") { // Pending
        dataURL = "data/data_workerSurvey.php?mod=pending&dateFrom=" + dateFrom + "&dateTo=" + dateTo + "&coid";
        $('#tab1_tblSurveyPending').DataTable().ajax.url(dataURL).load();
    } else if (activeTab == "#tab-2") { // Completed
        dataURL = "data/data_workerSurvey.php?mod=completed&dateFrom=" + dateFrom + "&dateTo=" + dateTo + "&coid=" + coid;
        $('#tab2_tblSurveyCompleted').DataTable().ajax.url(dataURL).load();
    } else { // All
        dataURL = "data/data_workerSurvey.php?mod=all&dateFrom=" + dateFrom + "&dateTo=" + dateTo + "&coid=" + coid;
        $('#tab3_tblSurveyAll').DataTable().ajax.url(dataURL).load();
    }
}
```

This is my db code

```
case "pending":
    $dateFrom = $_GET['dateFrom']; // Every time will have value
    $dateTo = $_GET['dateTo']; // Every time will have value
    $coid = $_GET['coid']; // This is not certain, depends on user selection
    $activeStatus = TRUE; // TRUE - Showing active worker; FALSE - showing inactive worker

    if ($activeStatus) {
        $whereClause = " AND a.biodata_status_id IN ('E', 'P') ";
    } else {
        $whereClause = " AND a.biodata_status_id = 'N' ";
    }

    if ($coid !== "" && $coid !== null) {
        $sql = "SELECT a.worker_id, a.worker_name, a.batchno, a.passport_no, a.company, a.arrival_date, a.plks, a.co_id, IF(DATEDIFF(a.plks, a.arrival_date) < 365 * 2, DATE_ADD(a.plks, INTERVAL 1 YEAR), a.plks) AS contract_end_date
            FROM rbs_worker a
            LEFT JOIN tbl_contract_extension_survey b ON (b.workerid = a.id AND b.status = 1 AND b.contract_end_date >= a.plks)
            LEFT JOIN rbs_payroll_company c ON c.co_id = a.co_id
            WHERE a.worker_id IS NOT NULL AND a.arrival_date IS NOT NULL AND a.plks IS NOT NULL 
                AND a.status = 'A' 
                AND a.co_id = %s
                AND IF(DATEDIFF(a.plks, a.arrival_date) < 365 * 2, DATE_ADD(a.plks, INTERVAL 1 YEAR), a.plks) >= %s 
                AND IF(DATEDIFF(a.plks, a.arrival_date) < 365 * 2, DATE_ADD(a.plks, INTERVAL 1 YEAR), a.plks) <= %s AND b.id IS NULL" . $whereClause;
        $rs = DB::query($sql, $coid, $dateFrom, $dateTo);
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT a.worker_id, a.worker_name, a.batchno, a.passport_no, a company, a.arrival_date, a.plks, a.co_id, IF(DATEDIFF(a.plks, a.arrival_date) < 365 * 2, DATE_ADD(a.plks, INTERVAL 1 YEAR), a.plks) AS contract_end_date 
            FROM rbs_worker a
            LEFT JOIN tbl_contract_extension_survey b ON (b.workerid = a.id AND b.status = 1 AND b.contract_end_date >= a.plks)
            LEFT JOIN rbs_payroll_company c ON c.co_id = a.co_id
            WHERE a.worker_id IS NOT NULL AND a.arrival_date IS NOT NULL AND a.plks IS NOT NULL 
                AND a.status = 'A' 
                AND IF(DATEDIFF(a.plks, a.arrival_date) < 365 * 2, DATE_ADD(a.plks, INTERVAL 1 YEAR), a.plks) >= %s 
                AND IF(DATEDIFF(a.plks, a.arrival_date) < 365 * 2, DATE_ADD(a.plks, INTERVAL 1 YEAR), a.plks) <= %s AND b.id IS NULL" . $whereClause;
        $rs = DB::query($sql, $dateFrom, $dateTo);
    }
```

I am expecting if the staff uncheck the box, they should able to view inactive worker data.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

You have the value of the checkbox as "active" but there is no JS code to control that, so it is always going to be active.

You have a variable "activeStatus" which gets the value of the checkbox, which as mentioned above is always "active", but you don't show where it is used. It's not appended to the dataURL anywhere, so it never gets sent to the server.

I guess that's why you set the $activeStatus in your DB code to true?! It should be $_GET['activeStatus'], which should be added to the dataURL, but not by means of checking the value, but by checking if the checked property is true or not.

A name/value combination is only good on a form field if you use the forms submit method. If you're using AJAX they are worthless, use id and the state/content of the field. So in this case:

```
// will be true or false
let activeStatus = $("#activeWorker").prop('checked');
```

...and then:

```
dataURL = "data/data_workerSurvey.php?mod=pending&activeStatus=" + activeStatus + "&dateFrom=" + dateFrom + "&dateTo=" + dateTo + "&coid";
```

Then in your DB code you could say:

```
$activeStatus = (bool)$_GET['activeStatus'];
```

Give that a try.

Comment: Hi Mr Paul Allsopp. Thanks for the info and explanation that you have provided. I have try the method but by default the checkbox will be checked ad the data will be displayed for active worker. I have try to include the code that you have provided, but the active worker data and the data that displayed not correct. Another thing is if I unchecked and checked back, the data are not changing

Comment: If the data does not change regardless of the state of the checkbox, then the state of the checkbox is really not being used when the data is fetched. Debug your SQL.